# UITableView(Cell) does not fill up entire screen

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

See this image:

[image]

The tableview does not fill up the screen, while I seated equal widths and heights to superview. I also tried to set the constrains to all zero's on leading trailing top and bottom. The black image you see has a trailing space of 5 to the content view, but the image is not on the far right side on iPad or iPhone 7.

How can I make the TableView as big as the screen? Thanks.

Comment: The correct way of doing this is as you mentioned; pin the `leading`, `trailing`, `top` and `bottom` constraints of the `UITableView` to the `superview` with a constant of `0`. Having said that, the `UITableViewCell` seems to cover the width of the simulated device so this could just be a rendering error in IB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove all constraints of your UITableView
2. Pin your UITableView to top, left, right and bottom with 0
3. Make sure not to use `constraints to margings`

[image]

Alternatively use the size inspectors Autoresizing.

[image]